# issues using first and mutate with group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I am using mutate to create a column depending on the first value of a group

```
library(tidyverse)
test = data.frame(grp = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3,1,2,3))

test
  grp x y
1   1 1 1
2   1 2 2
3   1 3 3
4   2 1 1
5   2 2 2
6   2 3 3

test %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(grp[[1]] == x[[1]], y-1, y))

    grp     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0
2     1     2     0
3     1     3     0
4     2     1     1
5     2     2     1
6     2     3     1
```

However output is not as I expected.
Expected output is

```
    grp     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0
2     1     2     1
3     1     3     2
4     2     1     1
5     2     2     2
6     2     3     3
```

Can you please explain what is happening and how best to get my expected solution?

Comment: by `y-1` you mean the lagged y right? Not just subtracting 1 from y values

Comment: no I want to subtract 1

Comment: Ok, just try this in your `ifelse`: `grp == first(x),...,...` so the whole chain would be `test %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(new_y = ifelse(grp == first(x), y-1, y))`

Comment: works! tyvm.  seems like you cannot use first or [[1]] on the grouping variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the index `[[1]]` from `grp` since it will only change the first value of that group and use that to replace `y`. Since `grp` is the group you should avoid indexing it. Just use it as is, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
 group_by(grp) %>% 
 mutate(new_y = ifelse(grp == first(x), y-1, y))

# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   grp [2]
    grp     x     y new_y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     0
2     1     2     2     1
3     1     3     3     2
4     2     1     1     1
5     2     2     2     2
6     2     3     3     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the x[[1]], you are always comparing the group values of each row with the the x value of the first row. I think you want grp==x within ifelse()

Comment: i want all y in the group to be decremented by 1.  also i don't think this is whats happening.  if you change it to grp[[2]] == x[[2]], you will still get the first row of y